# Add a shortcut to quick launch on taskbar on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, quicklaunch

I have a shortcut in some folder, I want to add it to quick launch bar. I tried to drag and drop it but it doesn't let me (I was able to do it in WinXP). How do I add a shortcut to my quick launch bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click on the taskbar. Toolbars -> add a new one. `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch` . Browse to this folder, click OK.

Mine is: `C:\Users\shiki.ayanami-PC\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch`

You can customize it with right click on the quick launch part and ... yeah. I usually hide the names, make the icons size small. It looks like this:

[image]